# How to adjust dates in the format "dd/mm/yyyy"

Tags: sql, oracle, regexp-replace, to-date, regexp-substr

I am trying to adjust dates from 'dd/mm/yyyy' to 'dd-mm-yy', but with no success.
In my dataset I have different date formats, so I though in way to filter them out to properly correct

Example:

```
  DATES
  -------
  09-MAY-18
  09-NOV-18
  09-OCT-18
  1/2/2017
  1/3/2017
  05/03/2018
  12-OCT-18
```

so, the dates '1/2/2017', '1/3/2017', '05/03/2018' should have the format 'DD-MM-YYYY' as the '09-MAY-18' or '09-NOV-18'.

the formula I tried to run is:

```
   UPDATE TESTE_DATAS SET DATAS = TO_DATE(REGEXP_REPLACE(DATAS, '^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$', 
                                    CONCAT(
                                      CONCAT(
                                        CONCAT(
                                          CONCAT(
                                                REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATAS, '^(\d+)(\/)(\d+)(\/)(\d+)$', 1, 1, 'i', 1),
                                                '-'),
                                                      REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATAS, '^(\d+)(\/)(\d+)(\/)(\d+)$', 1, 1, 'i', 3)),
                                                      '-'),
                                                         REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATAS, '^(\d+)(\/)(\d+)(\/)(\d+)$', 1, 1, 'i', 5)) 
                                        ),'DD-MM-YY') WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(DATAS,'^\d+\/\d+\/\d+$');
```

In the end I got the following:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

and the expected result should be:

```
  DATES
  -------
  09-MAY-18
  09-NOV-18
  09-OCT-18
  01-FEB-17
  01-MAR-17
  05-MAR-18
  12-OCT-18
```

Comment: Is the datatype of your column date or varchar2?

Comment: what version of the database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string to a date with `TO_DATE` first and then format the date with `TO_CHAR`:

```
update teste_datas set datas = to_char(to_date(datas, 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'DD-MON-YY') where datas like '%/%/%';
```

Comment: Hi @blhsing, I got no success:
      `Error at Command Line : 204 Column : 87`
      `Error report -`
      `SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DATES": invalid identifier`
      `00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`
      `*Cause:`    
      `*Action:`

Comment: The date column is named `DATAS`, not `DATES`, accordingly to your question. Fix the spelling and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

From the sample data, it seems there're three diffent different types of format for character type column `dates`.

Consider the code block below. If a formatting exception raises for converting to `'dd-MON-yy'`, the updating format to the other models is distinguished due to length

```
create table teste_datas( id int, dates varchar2(20),derived_date date);
insert all 
       into teste_datas(id,dates) values(1,'09-MAY-18')
       into teste_datas(id,dates) values(2,'1/2/2017')
       into teste_datas(id,dates) values(3,'05/03/2018')
select * from dual;

begin
    for d in ( select id, trim(dates) as dates from teste_datas order by id )
    loop
     begin  
      update teste_datas 
         set derived_date = to_date(d.dates,'dd-MON-yy')
       where id = d.id;
      exception when others then
       begin 
        if length(d.dates)<10 then 
          update teste_datas 
             set derived_date = to_date(d.dates,'mm/dd/yyyy')
           where id = d.id;       
        else   
          update teste_datas 
             set derived_date = to_date(d.dates,'dd/mm/yyyy')
           where id = d.id;       
        end if;   
       end;  
     end;    
    end loop;  
  end;  

  select * from teste_datas;

  ID    DATES       DERIVED_DATE
  ---   ----------  ------------
  1     09-MAY-18   09.05.2018
  2     1/2/2017    02.01.2017
  3     05/03/2018  05.03.2018

  select to_char(derived_date,'dd-MON-yy') as derived_date from teste_datas;

  DERIVED_DATE
  ------------
  09-MAY-18
  02-JAN-17
  05-MAR-18
```